# Login form not authenticating

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a login form for my website but currently, it is not working and I am being directed to invalid.php which shows my authentication has failed.

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     include("scripts/dbconnect.php");
     $numrows=0;
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     $query="select fname,lname,email from mayan_users where (password='$password' && email='$email')";
     $link = mysql_query($query);
     if (!$link) {
      die('login error');
     }
     $numrows=mysql_num_rows($link);
     if ($numrows>0){  // authentication is successfull
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($link, MYSQL_ASSOC);
      $_SESSION['user']['fname']=$row['fname'];
      $_SESSION['user']['lname']=$row['lname'];
      $_SESSION['user']['email']=$row['email'];
      header("location:../index2.php");
     } else {
      header("location:../invalid.php");  // authentication was unsuccessfull
     }
    ?>
```

and here is my login form

```
<div id="Loginform" style="background-color:fuchsia; width:100%">

<span id="logspan">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
     <input type="button" name="submit" style="cursor:pointer" id="submit" value="Log In" onclick="logMeIn()" />
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: What if I entered `') DROP TABLE mayan_users` for the e-mail field? [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Please, for the good or your users, don't store passwords in clear text in your database. Hash them with a salt before storage. (especially since this is vulnerable to SQL injection)

Comment: @Bondye The OP probably did use a tutorial from w3schools...

Comment: @jeroen Don't trust w3schools [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: i'm in univesity learning at the minute, and this is the first time i've done anything like this so obviously everything is not going to be perfect. how do i accept answers too?

Comment: Or his school is called W3

Comment: @BenThompson click the check mark next to the answer you want to accept (it is right underneath the up and down vote area on the left)

Comment: By the way, you should post your javascript as well as none of the answers if going to solve your problem if you are using ajax.

Comment: @Bondye whats the point in reponding in a negative way? He stated it was his first time. You said "This code is so bad" . Not constructive.

Comment: @AlbaClan at least some people understand the purpose behind this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your login may need to be to be wrapped in form tags if you aren't submitting it via some other method.

> ```
> <form method="post" action="">
>      <span id="logspan">
>          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
>          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
>          <input type="button" name="submit" style="cursor:pointer" id="submit" value="Log In" onclick="logMeIn()" />
>      </span>
> </form>
> ```

If your PHP is in another document then set the action to the form processor

```
action="form-processor.php"
```

(Thanks njk!)

Comment: if he is posting to the same document then an action isn't needed

Comment: I'm not sure what the effect is of leaving it out (in all browsers...), but officially it is required: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: my bad, thanks for the official documentation. apparently i was mistaken!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the form tags.Add them like this

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<!-- INSERT INPUTS HERE -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="Loginform" style="background-color:fuchsia; width:100%">

<span id="logspan">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
     <input type="button" name="submit" style="cursor:pointer" id="submit" value="Log In" onclick="logMeIn()" />
    </span>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to use PDO if your PHP version support it.
Then I suppose that your javascript function sends in the correct way the parameters.
Finally, you could avoid to check the number of rows. Simply

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($link))
{
  ...
}
else
{
  header("location: ../invalid.php");
  exit; //It's a good practice
}
```